# IP restrictions when authenticating named credentials

Tags: security, namedcredentials, ip

I'm trying to create a named credential for accessing in-house services from salesforce.

For that I've setup an authentication provider:

```
type: Open ID Connect

Authorize Endpoint URL: https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize

Token Endpoint URL: https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
```

The named credential has the following settings:

```
Identity Type:  Per User

Authentication Protocol:    OAuth 2.0

Scope:  refresh_token full
```

When going to my user settings and setting up "Authentication Settings for External Systems" and using the named credential i created, I get an authentication error once I attempt to authenticate. I get "invalid grant ip restricted".

The login history on my user has registered a login attempt from 85.222.138.8 from the UK, and it also states that the login failed due to IP restriction. A tracert translates the IP to "proxy-par.net.salesforce.com". Once I whitelist this IP, everything works as intended. But is this the only IP that needs to be whitelisted?

I've checked: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321501&type=1&mode=1 but the IP is not on the list.

I also got an open case with Salesforce, but the guy with ownership doesn't understand the issue unfortunately. I'm trying my luck here :)

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce provides a list of IPs need to be whitelisted in these scenarios. The IP list is based on the location of the Salesforce Org. Please check this help article for the detail list of IPs.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003652&type=1

Comment: The ip in question (85.222.138.8) is not on the list, nor is it in any of the ranges. I also wrote this in my question already.